# How to set #(area) links in HTML?

Tags: html

On my site, I have a blog.

For post 1 I want to be able to type
example.com/blog.html#post-1 to get to post 1
For post 76 I want to type
example.com/blog.html#post-76 to get to it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this javascript line to read the parameter after hash:

```js
var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```